# What probiotics work for irritable bowel syndrome, according to Genome Medicine?

Tags: probiotics, irritable-bowel-syndrome, diarrhea, gut-microbiota-flora, ulcerative-colitis

According to the [Chicago Tribune](http://www.chicagotribune.com/lifestyles/health/ct-probiotics-pros-and-cons-20160920-story.html), a study was published in the journal *Genome Medicine* that indicated that some probiotics work for irritable bowel syndrome (IBS):

> In a study published in May in the journal Genome Medicine, the researchers narrowed down the hundreds of studies to seven that fit certain criteria: They used healthy adults and included a control group and a DNA-based identification of the various bacterial strains. Pedersen's group found that some probiotics work for irritable bowel syndrome, ulcerative colitis and travelers' diarrhea. With these ailments, the variety of normally occurring bacteria - called the microbiotic "flora" - may be disturbed or knocked out of balance.

I was not able to locate this study.  Which probiotics work for IBS, according to this study, and did they identify whether they work for IBS-C or IBS-D?

Answer (score 1):

[**Some IBS patients benefit from probiotic supplements. Those with the best efficacy include Align, Culturelle and VSL#3.**](http://www.chicagotribune.com/lifestyles/food/sns-201608221300--tms--foodstylts--v-f20160822-20160822-story.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have it on good authority that bacillus coagulans and saccharomyces boulardii are effective at combating C. difficile, which is largely responsible for IBS. Here are a couple of citations from respectable sources: [bacillus coagulans](https://medlineplus.gov/druginfo/natural/1185.html) and [saccharomyces boulardii](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3296087/).